# Undo clone remote branch to local

Tags: git, github

I done messed up good this time.

Basically, I had done some work on an entirelly new project while offline. Now that I'm back online, I wanted to put it in git. Running `git init` told me that I already had an existing repo in that location (though I don't remember doing that), but there were no changes to commit (I realize now the files were probably just untracked).

What I ended up doing, was to create a new private repo on GitHub, and then clone that to my local repo. I naïvely figured that would make me able to `add`, `commit` and `push` my local changes to remote.

However, it simply replaced my local repo with the empty remote, thus deleting all my local files.

Fortunatelly, I have some of the files open in my editor, so I can simply save the changes, but I will have to piece together what is missing.

Now, this is kind of a long shot, but is there a way to undo this mess?

Comment: First, with a `git init` you can always do `ADD` and `COMMIT`, because they are local. To remote, you can only do the `PUSH`. When you already have a repo, you can create your remote, but instead of cloning (to link them), you just do a `git remote add`. Keep this in mind for future needs. On your particular problem, if files were really removed for good, perhaps a hard disk file recovery tool can help.

Comment: @Lovato Yup. I know all this, but I suffered a serious case of acute brain fart. It's no biggie, I will simply recreate from scratch. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how (with which tool or command) you cloned the new repository over your existing local directory. Since that local directory was an already initialized Git repository, either you somehow deleted and recreated it and then it's likely dead to restore anything, either you actually only added a new remote and updated the working directory with a new branch, dropping some commits, forcing a history rewrite or anything like this. In that latter case, then you may be able to retrieve your lost commits with `git fsck --lost-found` then optionally use `git reflog`, `git show`, `git cherry-pick`...

Comment: As explained in the OP, running `git init` told me I already had a local repo, however I could not commit my changes. I think they were simply untracked, even if it recognized files had been changed. I also could not add a remote (`git remote add origin https://github.com/TheNix/myawesomeproject.git`) or push anything (no commits, remember?). I then simply clicked the handy "Set up in Desktop" button, that Github has. This launches their own app, which does unknown magic. It warned me that existing files could be overwritten, but I didn't expect it to delete everything else.

Comment: No commit. OK, sorry. So it's dead. No luck.